# Why does the Java compiler say my file was not found in the class path when I can clearly see it in the class path?

Tags: java

I am using `java -classpath $CLASSPATH ...`, where `$CLASSPATH` has been set to `/file1path/file1:/file2path/file2` and so on.  Despite this, Java complains that `file1` is not found.  I tried to set `-Dfile1=file:///fullpath/file1`, but it still says it cannot find the file.  Is there any reason why this might happen other than that I am not seeing a simpler problem like a typo or something (which I have checked for many times)?

More specifically, `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(configurationFileName)` is returning `null`.

The file that is not being found is a configuration file (.properties), not a JAR file.

Comment: Is the file a class file that is not found? If not, is the file part of a jar?

Comment: How are you looking for the file to get the error? Are you talking about a .java file, a .properties file or similar, etc.? I'm assuming you are invoking java directly without an IDE? Also, if you're looking in your source folder and if you're using a separate class folder, are you sure the file is being compiled to the class folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set a `classpath` to point to a directory containing something or an archive containing resources. I don't believe you can add a resource directly to the `classpath`.

Try setting your `classpath` to `/file1path` instead of `/file1path/file1`

Comment: It seems that files have been added directly to the classpath previously and this had been working.

Comment: I'm really surprised to hear that. I've never seen that in action and I just tried a little test myself and referencing a file directly didn't work. Is this Sun JVM?

Comment: Also, is there any chance the files being referenced happen to be in a directory or jar in the classpath?

Comment: I don't know how the code here has been working previously, but the minute I changed the class path to point to a path rather than to a file, it worked.

Comment: I can only imagine the file you were referencing was in the classpath inside a JAR file or a directory and the presence of the file directly on the classpath was misleading you. If the code was still working you could call `getResource` which should give you the URL to the location from where the file is loaded.

Answer (score 3):

The classpath should specify the directory where your package hierarchy rooted.

package org.djna, file system : `C:/myhome/javastuff/org/djna/Myclass.java`

classpath is set to `c:/myhome/javastuff`

If you are trying to open files from your application using `getResourceAsStream()` or some such the the details of the path depend on whether or not the filename has a leading `/`. Read the docs caefully and all will become clear.

Comment: I am reading http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29 and all has not become clear.  Are there some other docs you're referring to that might be more helpful?

Comment: The slash doesn't seem to have anything to do with it.